# Javascript flip/mirror an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, transformation, image-rotation

Does anyone know if its possible to flip an image and have content on its back. This is what I mean:
Imagine holding a portrait in your hand. You then flip and look at the BACK of the portrait and the back has writing there. Im looking for something like that, that onClick the image will mirror/flip to the other side which will have writing on it. No 90 180 degree rotation. Its kind of a 3rd dimension rotation. Does anyone know if thats possible? and if so, how?
Thanks

Comment: In a word, no. You can simulate it by having another image with the contents of the "back" and you can use animation to simulate rotation

Comment: would you care to explain, point in the right direction, show me code please?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with CSS3 there's a link on Google I cannot find rigt now...

Comment: try writing some jquery using the animate method to change the width of your image to 0 and then have a div with overflow hidden and 0 width that you animate to full width, that should give you the desired effect

Comment: Of course [it is possible in CSS3](http://css3playground.com/flip-card.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Flip jQuery plugin and its demo](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) or [QuickFlip](http://jonraasch.com/blog/quickflip-2-jquery-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the scale option in css with negative values. that flips an image.
Then you also have 3dtransforms in css.
Together with javascript they give nice effects.